# CSV appears to be corrupt on Double quotes in Headers - C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to read CSV file in C#.

I have tried `File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(a => a.Split(';'))` way but the issue is when there is `\n` multiple line in a cell it is not working.

So I have tried below

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

            var csvTable = new DataTable();
            using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(path))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(fileReader, false))
            {
                csvTable.Load(csvReader);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < csvTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               if (!(csvTable.Rows[i][0] is DBNull))
                {
                    var row1= csvTable.Rows[i][0];
                }
               if (!(csvTable.Rows[i][1] is DBNull))
                {
                    var row2= csvTable.Rows[i][1];
                }
            }
```

The issue is the above code throwing exception as
`The CSV appears to be corrupt near record '0' field '5 at position '63'`
This is because the header of CSV's having two double quote as below

```
"Header1",""Header2""
```

Is there a way that I can ignore double quotes and process the CSV's.
`update`

I have tried with `TextFieldParser` as below

```
     public static void GetCSVData()
        {
            using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
            {
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
                parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
                while (parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
                {
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                    foreach (var field in fields)
                    {
                        Console.Write(field + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
```

The output:
[image]

Sample CSV data I have used:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `TextFieldParser` if you want to stick with standard .NET or else use a dedicated library like CSVHelper. Otherwise, you're going to have to write code to explicitly handle quoted values.

Comment: I have tried `TextFieldParser` but it is not working when a cell has multiple lines.

Comment: The `TextFieldParser` handles quoted input containing line breaks. If it didn't work for you then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did then it wrong. If you don't show us what you did then we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I just noticed that your code uses a `CsvHelper`. Sorry, I missed that the first time. Never used that class so can't help with it. In fact, I think I may have misread the question quite badly the first time. Shouldn't have rushed it.

Comment: The data you showed at the end, i.e. `"Header1",""Header2""`, is not valid in a CSV. Any tool intended to read valid CSV files will consider that corrupt. Either use a valid CSV file or write custom code to handle your custom data format. If you want a valid CSV file then you can wrap a value in a pair of double quotes and you can include double quotes in a value by escaping them with another double quote. Anything else is not valid. In short, the error message is correct so either fix your data or write your own parsing code.

Comment: this library has a setting for a mode, to handle your case: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs - maybe consider switching the library | example usages can be found here: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/tests/CsvHelper.Tests/Parsing/CsvModeTests.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works!

Please replace two double quotes as below from csv:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();

    // replace "" with "
    contents = contents.Replace("\"\"", "\"");

    // go back to the beginning of the stream
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // adjust the length to make sure all original
    // contents is overritten
    fs.SetLength(contents.Length);

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.Write(contents);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Then use the same CSV helper

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

var csvTable = new DataTable();
using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(path))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(fileReader, false))
{
    csvTable.Load(csvReader);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Notice, that if the string would contain 3 double quotes you would end up with 2 double quotes. - https://dotnetfiddle.net/dayUJr

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a valid way to solve this problem.

Comment: I found Solution from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad5dddfc-f5e1-4568-b08f-6084d6cb171c/remove-double-quotes-from-csv-file?forum=csharplanguage where you can handle the all double quotes `contents.Replace("\"\"", "");`  to empty based on the issue.